# Are global or local variables more efficient?

Tags: c++

It's very common in games to calculate the time it took to render the last frame (delta time) in order to produce smooth movement, timers, etc.

One way of doing this would be to declare 3 global variables:

```
float deltaTime, currentTime, elapsedTime;
```

and then calculate the delta time at the start of the game loop:

```
currentTime = getTime();
deltaTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
elapsedTime = currentTime;
```

*(where getTime() is a function that return the time since the program started)*

Another way of doing it would be to declare *deltaTime* and *currentTime* as local variables:

```
float currentTime = glfwGetTime();
float deltaTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
elapsedTime = currentTime;
```

If my understanding is correct, the compiler then has to deallocate the memory of the variables at the end of the loop and, in the next iteration of the loop, reallocate it all over again causing it to be more inefficient than just declaring global variables.

Is this correct or is there some other stuff automagically happening in the background that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Local variables can be faster because the optimizer can store them in registers.

Comment: In C++ *in general*, you can't make a statement about the performance difference. In most x86 implementations, however, local variables end up on the stack (or in registers, as rustyx mentions); stack allocation/deallocation of primitive types happens as part of calling the function (ergo, it's free), and the same goes for register allocation.

Comment: Global vs local variables should be more about symbol scoping than memory lifetime. As stated, actual performance implications vary from a platform to another, and I doubt profiling this case would reveal any big difference.

Comment: [When a local variable is defined, it is not initialized by the system, you must initialize it yourself. Global variables are initialized automatically by the system when you define them...](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

Comment: In addition, global states have to be updated (may incur cache misses...), whereas local are in register or on stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If my understanding is correct, the compiler then has to deallocate the memory of the variables at the end of the loop and, in the next iteration of the loop, reallocate it all over again causing it to be more inefficient than just declaring global variables.

That's not true.

Compilers don't allocate and deallocate memory for local variables in a loop. Memory for local variables in a functions is, usually, allocated when the stack frame for a function is created.

The variables are initialized in each run of the loop.

If the variable is a class type that has a constructor and destructor, they will be called in each run of the loop, which could be expensive depending on what happens in the constructor and the destructor, the number of times the loop is run.

For a `float` type, there shouldn't be any overhead due to use of a local variable in a loop. I will be very surprised if there is any.

Comment: And as a rule of thumb, allocating a stack frame takes one instruction (can be more for excessive stack frames, but still way less than one instruction per local variable).

Answer (score 1):

source code:

```
extern float getTime();
float deltaTime, currentTime = getTime(), elapsedTime = getTime();

float time_it()
{
  currentTime = getTime();
  deltaTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
  elapsedTime = currentTime;
  return deltaTime;
}
```

object code:

```
time_it():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    getTime()
        vmovss  DWORD PTR currentTime[rip], xmm0
        vmovaps xmm1, xmm0
        vsubss  xmm0, xmm0, DWORD PTR elapsedTime[rip]
        vmovss  DWORD PTR elapsedTime[rip], xmm1
        vmovss  DWORD PTR deltaTime[rip], xmm0
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

what's significant?

`call    getTime()` - by far the most expensive operation on any system

`vmovss  DWORD PTR currentTime[rip], xmm0` one memory write

one memory fetch:
`vsubss  xmm0, xmm0, DWORD PTR elapsedTime[rip]`

two memory writes, one of them is redundant.

`vmovss  DWORD PTR elapsedTime[rip], xmm1`
`vmovss  DWORD PTR deltaTime[rip], xmm0`

Total overhead of storing deltaTime in a global is one memory write. Nothing to get excited about performance-wise, but certainly unwelcome style-wise.

The reason to avoid globals has nothing to do with performance, it has everything to do with avoiding tight coupling.

Comment: To pick at nits:  You are showing *assembly code* not object code.  Object code is usually more binary in nature and not human readable.  The assembly language code is compiled (translated) into object code, which is then linked by the linker.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews forgive me. I have not written object code since I used to patch eproms in an eprom programmer because that was faster than the assembler running on a DX10 way back in...1986. ;-)