# Should I initialize a variable in a function or globally?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, game-engine

I'm writing my own game engine in C++ and I was wondering where should I initialize variables which I need every frame, for example, every time mouse pointer is getting moved, the coordinates of pointer position should be saved in a variable.
Should I initialize the variable for that globally or in the function where it always initializes the variable new? Where are the benefits and where are the disadvantages?

```cpp
float offsetX
float offsetY
void mouse_callback(double posX, double posY) {
    offsetX = posX - lastX;
    offsetY = lastY - posY;
    lastX = posX;
    lastY = posY;
}
```

or

```cpp
void mouse_callback(double posX, double posY) {
    float offsetX = posX - lastX;
    float offsetY = lastY - posY;
    lastX = posX;
    lastY = posY;
}
```

Comment: The fewer global variables you have, the easier it will be to reason about your code, and the easier it will be to debug your code.  But if you have to have a global variable, it needs to be initialized before it is used.  When and where that's best depends on your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables should be defined *as closely* as possible to where they are used. The longer the distance between declaration and initialization, the more error prone the code will be.

A good thing about having the variables defined in the function, is that you can mark them as `const`(!). Then you notify the readers of the code, that these variables will never change.

Remember that you write code for people and not for the compiler. For this simple use case, there will probably be *no* difference in memory nor speed - the compiler will be able to optimize away the variables.

Comment: Thanks! @Mikael H this helps me a lot. The Quote: "Remember that you write code for people and not for the compiler" opened my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

> Should I initialize the variable for that globally or in the function where it always initializes the variable new?

I think you're confusing *initialization* with *declaration*. Looking at your code:

> ```
> void mouse_callback(double posX, double posY) {
>     float offsetX = posX - lastX;
>     float offsetY = lastY - posY;
>     lastX = posX;
>     lastY = posY;
> }
> ```

Here, you're *declaring* `offsetX` and `offsetY` to be local variables, and initializing them to `posX - lastX` etc. But then you don't do anything further with those variables, and the values you calculated will disappear as soon as `mouse_callback()` exits. If you're actually using `offsetX` and `offsetY` inside `mouse_callback()` in your actual code and you don't need them anywhere else, that's probably fine. But as written above, you could just delete the first two lines in the body of the function and the function would still behave exactly the same.

`lastX` and `lastY` are clearly meant to be variables with longer lifetimes (i.e. global variables or perhaps instance variables in a class) because you use them in `mouse_callback()` without either declaring them or initializing them. Those clearly need to have valid values before `mouse_callback()` is called, because you're using them in the first two lines.

In general, the main thing that you need to know is that *all* variables need to be initialized, i.e. given valid values, before you use their values. Except for objects where initialization might be slow or resource-intensive, there isn't much reason not to initialize variables when you declare them, whether they're global or local, and doing so will help you avoid bugs that can be hard to track down.

Answer (score 0):

It fully depends on your code.
If you need those variables just in one function (or class), initialize them inside it. But if you need it on multiple functions (globally), you may initialize them globally.
Using less global variables (usually) makes your code more memory efficient, faster and safer. Search Google (or Bing like me!) for "global variables" for more information.

Comment: nobody needs global variables

Comment: He's writing C++ not C and this is the 21 century. Also, if he needed the variables outside the function, he would not think about only defining them in the function.

Comment: @JoKing He asked about differences and I said some of them. I didn't write you **must** use global variables; I wrote **may**.

Answer (score -1):

This is a question about optimization versus readability. Having the variables as class members is slightly faster. But readability dictates to create variables only were they are needed. So long as you do not need the slight improvement in speed, keep them in the function.

Comment: There are no classes in the example though. It's about global variables vs local variables.

Comment: The question is about global vs. local, it does not mention classes or members. And It isn't true that class members are faster than local variables.

Comment: well, he better use a class ;) ... anyways... it applies equally

Comment: Also from the example it is not clear, that there is no class. Only the word globally lets u assume that there is none. Since I'm not sure if OP knows what the word globally implies I translated it with "outside the function" and assumed, that he uses classes when he is about to implement a whole game engine. Can I get my votes back? :P

Answer (score -1):

Local variables are shown in all debuggers (global are not) and are faster than global variables, but there is less available memory for local variables and you can use them in different functions. Choose what's better for you.

Comment: Can you support "local variables are faster than global variables"?

Comment: There are stack memory and heap memory. Stack works better than the heap, because of implementation (there is faster to allocate memory for stack, see [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))).

Comment: @DenisTereshchenko No

Comment: @JoKing Why not?

Comment: @DenisTereshchenko Globals are allocated only once. In practice stack based trivial objects are all allocated at once by moving the stack pointer. Both global and local allocation time are not relevant for trivial objects.

Comment: @DenisTereshchenko What you said is **usually** correct, but not always; for example, if you declare and define lots of variables each time you call a function rather that declaring them just once and globally, it may reduce speed. But there are also other things to take care beside speed (memory efficiency, security, ...).

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39045995/13595835

Comment: See [Are global variables in C++ stored on the stack, heap or neither of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360074/643383). Also, if your debugger doesn't show global variables, you should get a new debugger.

Comment: @Caleb My debugger shows them, but I know many that aren't.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that *any* debugger in common use doesn't show global variables; not being able to examine the complete state of a program would significantly diminish the utility of the debugger in the first place. But, moving on... the problem with this answer is that the claims you make are largely unsupportable, and to the extent that they have any validity it's not really relevant to the OP's question. E.g., the relative sizes of stack and heap don't make much difference when the OP is asking about a few floats.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for reviewing my answer! As you probably see, I'm a newbie, so I know not very much about Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @DenisTereshchenko Thanks for contributing. Keep reading, asking, and answering... new users keep the site strong.